# Best method to find Zin of a BJT

Tags: rf, analog, bjt, ltspice, simulation

[image]

I am trying to reconcile how to find the Zin of a non-bypassed low frequency (~1 MHz) CE amplifier.

If I google [common emitter input impedance](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/input-impedance-of-an-amplifier.html) I find this (where re = Vt/Ie). Ok, great.

When I simulate a CE amplifier on LT-spice and measure its input impedance via plotting V1 / I(V1) * -1, the simulated Zin is smaller than the website calculation method by a factor of >= 10. What could be causing this discrepancy? I don't think parasitic capacitances would take effect at these frequencies. Which method is more accurate at frequencies near 1 MHz?

[image]

Edit: I changed the AC analysis to include lower frequencies and the impedance values of both methods were nearly a match; It seems parasitic picofarad capacitances take effect at frequencies as low as 100 KHz.

[image]

Comment: Parasitic capacitances (base-emitter, base-collector) *definitely* dominate the input impedance in your circuit.

Comment: @JonathanS. Feel free to post your comment as an answer!

Comment: @YousifAlniemi You are allowed to write your own answer to your question and to select it. May as well as I think you understand the key issues.

Comment: In the formula for Zin as given above the resistors R1 and R2 belong to the base voltage divider. That means: R1 is NOT the resistor in the collector path. In your case - with R2 only for base biasing - you have to consider R2 only.

Comment: @LvW  I eventually caught on to that; I am still learning about the hybrid pi model and AC analysis which I hope to use for more accurate impedance calculations at my frequency of interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yousif, I know that many work with this pi-model. But in my opinion, such models are too abstract and do not help in understanding the circuit.

Do you know, for example, what is meant by "re" (it does not appear in the pi-model).

**Let me try an explanation based on the real circuit diagram:**

If you look at the circuit, it is clear that the total input resistance r_in,tot is composed of the **parallel connection** of the external resistors at the base node (**RB**) and the dynamic differential input resistance of the transistor (**r_in**) at the base with **r_in=r_be+beta*RE.**

In this expression, r_be is the differential resistance of the base-emitter path and beta is the small signal current gain.

**Explanation**: Because the beta-fold current flows through the resistor RE (compared to the base current), this resistor also acts with the beta-fold value.

**Explanation to "re"**: The collector current Ic of the bipolar transistor is controlled by the base-emitter voltage Vbe, which defines the transconductance "gm":

**gm=d(Ic)/d(Vbe)=[d(Ic)/d(Ib)]/[d(Vbe/d(Ib)]=beta/r_be**

**gm=beta/r_be.**

Some authors use the reciprocal of the slope **re=1/gm=r_be/beta** and thus
**r_be=beta*re**

This then gives (see the formula in your question) :

**r_in=r_be+beta*RE=beta(re + RE)**

Again, the total input resistor is **r_in,tot=RB||r_in**

I have tried a clear explanation here without using a transistor model.

---

A last note to the transconductance gm=1/re: It is nothing else than the **slope** of the Ic=f(Vbe) characteristic **Ic=Is[exp(Vbe/Vt)].** The slope of this exponential function can easily found to be: **gm=Ic/Vt.**

Therefore, for finding the total input resistance you only need the external resistors, the DC current Ic and the current gain beta.

Comment: Thanks for the intuitive derivation, I drew out your steps on paper and it clicked. Gm=Ic/Vbe --> d(Ic)/d(Ib) * d(Ib)/d(Vbe) leaves us d(Ic)/d(Vbe) which has inverse units of resistance. Gm = B * (1/units of inverse resistance) elucidates where rbe comes from! Interesting information about thermal voltage too.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the AC analysis to include lower frequencies and the impedance values of both methods were nearly a match.

It seems that parasitic picofarad capacitances take effect at frequencies as low as 100 KHz.

That is - what I considered "low" frequency was not actually low.

Comment: You did it the wrong way around. You edited your answer into the question, and then posted a comment as an answer. The answer field is exclusively reserved for actual answers.

Comment: @Velvel Thanks - i edited his answer to make it one, using his text.